# Java: Using .txt files to assign specific indexes of each line to an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, file-io

My .txt file is

```
code1,description1,price1
code2,description2,price2
etc.
```

Using:

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
String description;
File fn = new File("file.txt");
String[] astring = new String[4];
try{
 Scanner readFile = new Scanner(fn);
 Scanner as = new Scanner(System.in);
 while (readFile.hasNext()){
  astring = readFile.nextLine().split(",");
  String code = astring[0];
  items.add(code);
  description = astring[1];
}
}catch(FileNotFoundException){
//
}

for(String things: items){
 System.out.println("The code is: " + things + "The description is " + description);
}
```

My output prints out

```
code1 description1
code2 description1
code3 description1
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make the description update as the code's do. e.g.

```
code1 description1
code2 description2
code3 description3
```

If this question has been asked already, I apologize. I couldn't find out how to do it by searching around but if there's a reference to figure this out I'll close this down and go there. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `astring` variable has an unnecessarily broad scope. Should be declared in the `while` loop

Comment: `code` is incrementing because you are iterating `items`, `description` not because it's not related to that array.

Comment: So how would I get the descriptions to update within items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your logic. You are storing only `astring[0]` to the `items` ArrayList and overwriting the value of `description` each time. As a result on last value read is stored in `description` which you are printing in the loop.

I prefer creating a custom class as follows. (Just for the sake of demo otherwise you would declare your fields as private and provide getters and setters)

```
class MyObject {
 public String code;
 public String description;
 public String price;
}
```

now instead of creating ArrayList of Strings you will create ArrayList of MyObject as follows

```
ArrayList<MyObject> items = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
```

now create a new instance of MyObject each time you read a line , populate its fields with the values from `astring` as follows

```
ArrayList<MyObject> items = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    File fn = new File("test.txt");
    String[] astring = new String[4];
    try {
        Scanner readFile = new Scanner(fn);
        Scanner as = new Scanner(System.in);
        MyObject myObject;
        while (readFile.hasNext()) {
            astring = readFile.nextLine().split(",");
            myObject = new MyObject();

            myObject.code = astring[0];
            myObject.description  = astring[1];
            myObject.price = astring[2];

            items.add(myObject);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

and then finally print it using the same foreach loop as follows

```
for (MyObject item : items) {
        System.out.println("The code is: " + item.code + " The description is: " + item.description + " The price is: " + item.price);
    }
```

**Output**

```
The code is: code1 The description is: description1 The price is: price1
The code is: code2 The description is: description2 The price is: price2
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I was needing to refer from a class anyways so this is perfect.

Comment: @Auron Kelmud Glad to help

Comment: @Mehdi I promise I didn't copy your code. As soon as I was done composing my answer and hit submit I saw your answer already posted with identical solutions. It was pure coincidence

Comment: @SyedAhmedJamil my answer has posted 11 min before your answer! You just got the idea, refactored the code and then posted it.

Comment: @Mehdi I was on the composing my answer screen when meanwhile you posted your answer. I really didn't look at your answer until I submitted mine.

Comment: @Mehdi
Late reply, but if I wanted to use the codes for a if condition then how would I do that? e.g. if(choice.equals(item.code)){//(code1 or code2)
//do stuff
}
When I try it that way, it stops directly at the first code. Would I have to add each code to a list or some sort or is there a way to force the loop to allow choice access to each indvidual code?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're seeing that output is that you are **not** saving description along with the code **inside the list**, that is why the last description is saved within the description variable not all description values.

> To solve this problem, you can create a simple **Java Bean/POJO** class
>   and wrap your data inside it and then you can simply fetch the value
>   you have saved it and then show it properly. Take a look at the code
>   below:

```
public class Launcher{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        File fn = new File("file.txt");

        try {
            Scanner readFile = new Scanner(fn);
            while (readFile.hasNext()) {
                String[] astring = readFile.nextLine().split(",");
                String code = astring[0];
                String description = astring[1];
                String price = astring[2];
                Item item = new Item(code, description, price);
                items.add(item);

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException d) { // }

        }

        for (Item thing : items) {
            System.out.println(String.format("The code is: %s\tThe description is: %s\tThe Price is %s",thing.getCode(),thing.getDescription(), thing.getPrice()));
        }
    }
}

class Item {
    private String code;
    private String description;
    private String price;

    public Item(String code, String description, String price) {
        this.code = code;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This works like a charm and is exactly what I was trying to accomplish.